# Tensor template dimensions, failing template deduction

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement a tensor class in C++ where the tensors dimensions are given as template arguments of the class. Trivially, it would look like this:

```
template <size_t... TDims>
class Tensor
{/*...*/};
```

The problem with this is that types `Tensor<2, 1>` and `Tensor<2>` should be the same, even though they aren't. For example, I would want the matrix multiplication of `Tensor<3, 7>` and `Tensor<7>` to return a `Tensor<3>`, and not (just) a `Tensor<3, 1>`.

One way to solve this is to implement a kind of meta template function that removes all ones from the end of `TDims` like so (`NumberSequence` is just a single type that contains several number constants):

```
namespace detail {
    template <NumberSequence TDimSequence>
    class Tensor
    {/*...*/};
}

template <size_t... TDims>
using Tensor = detail::Tensor<typename RemoveOnesFromEnd<TDims...>::type>;
```

This makes `Tensor<2>` and `Tensor <2, 1>` actually be the very same type. I successfully implemented `struct RemoveOnesFromEnd` to do what it is supposed to do, but this opens up another problem: Taking a `Tensor` as a function parameter now prevents the deduction of template parameters. For example with this matrix multiplication the compiler can't deduce the three `size_t` values when given two tensors:

```
template <size_t TRows1, size_t TCols1Rows2, size_t TCols2>
Tensor<TRows1, TCols2> multiply(Tensor<TRows1, TCols1Rows2> t1, Tensor<TCols1Rows2, TCols2> t2)
{/*...*/}
```

In theory, it is well-defined what values the `size_t` parameters should have, yet due to the levels of indirection that `RemoveOnesFromEnd` adds the compiler can't handle it.

- Do you know of a way to make `Tensor<2, 1>` and `Tensor<2>` be the exact same type while at the same time allowing for successful template parameter deduction?

Another kind of solution would be to have `Tensor<..., 1>` inherit from `Tensor<...>` until there is no 1 at the end, but from what I can tell it would run into the same problems with template deduction that the previous solution would, since I would have to have a meta template function to reverse the dimensions of the tensor so that I can check whether the last dimension is a 1 or not (because I am only able to check parameters appearing *before* a parameter pack), which would then add the same problematic levels of indirection. In fact, I am using a reversing technique in `RemoveOnesFromEnd` as well.

- Do you know of another way to reference template parameters at the end of or after a parameter pack that would avoid the problem with template deduction?

Comment: Consider using default template parameters instead of variadic templates e.g. `template <size_t A, size_t B = 1, size_t C = 1, size_t D = 1, size_t E = 1, size_t F = 1> struct Tensor { /* implementation */ };`. This way instantiation of `Tensor<3>` would be actually instantiation of `Tensor<3,1,1,1,1,1>`...

Comment: That could be a solution, though it would make the code somewhat inelegant, and it would disallow for tensors with arbitrarily high rank. If there's no other way, I will probably end up doing it this way, but I'd definitely prefer if it could somehow work with variadic templates. Also, a similar approach with variadic templates wouldn't work, since I'd have to insert an infinite amount of ones.

Comment: Another option is to provide implicit conversions adding and removing trailing ones. Rather than having a helper `RemoveTrailingOnes<TDims...>` you would have a helper `SameUpToTrailingOnes<TDims1..., TDims2...>`

Comment: @Caleth Could you show me a short example?

Comment: Modulo template wizardry, you want `int[1]` to be the same type as `int`, right?

Comment: Also, do you want to remove leading and/or internal dimensions of 1?